# Mongoose/MongoDB update is not working

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I know this question has been beaten to death on here, but I have tried everything and cannot fix this. It is driving me mad.

I have a model that looks like this:

```
customer {
 email: String,
 password: String,
 addresses: [addresses_schema]
}
```

and addresses_schema looks like

```
address {
 addr1: String,
 ... Other address fields
 primary_address: Boolean
}
```

Now, I want to update a particular address record of a user to have a primary_address of true.

So I do:

```
var modifyUser = function(address_id){
  User.findOne( { email: email } ).then(function(user){
    user.update({ 'addresses._id': address_id }, 
                { $set: { 'addresses.$.primary_address': 'true' } } )

       .then(function(){
         console.log('Should eventually reach here');
        }).catch (err) {
           console.log('err:', err.message);
         });


    user.save();
  });
}
```

However, if I grab user.addresses before and after the update, nothing changes at all. Instead it gives me the error:

```
cannot use the part (addresses of addresses._id) to traverse the element ({addresses[ {addr1: '123 test street', addr2: '', city: 'test city' ... ]}
```

Can someone help me? I would really appreciate it. Thank you!

Comment: I don't see any callbacks here. Are you trying to return this directly from a function call?

Comment: @BlakesSeven There's ~300 lines of code below it I didn't want to copy paste here. I am not trying to return it, I just want to update my User I found. I have updated my question.

Comment: Show a "minimal example" of processing the `.update()` and then looking at the data. You probably really want [`.findOneAnUpdate()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOneAndUpdate) anyway. But my main point is there is no promise or callback on the `.update()` here, so at the very least it probably has not "fired" by the time you are looking at the data. You need to show a bit more than *"More code after this"*. Show what really happens ( in breif ), but the main actions.

Comment: @BlakesSeven, actually, the update is the meat of the code. Attaching a then call to the update gives some more information. I will update this again in a few minutes after I dig into that.

Comment: "Minimal case". Should take you 2 minutes to write. Create document, find it, update it, read it back. But your code here does not even show the update executing at all. That is what I asked you to add. `user.update()` does nothing. It needs to be executed. As well it should be `User.update()` and likely the whole thing should be `.findOneAnUpdate()` as mentioned earlier. If you have 300 lines of code manipulating then calling `.save()` then that is **bad**.

Comment: I deleted literally everything and added the above code verbatim and got that error message.

Comment: That's better. But the error implies that you are not actually using the positional `$` operator at all, which is in contrast to the code that you list. Still worried there is a bit too much editing here and you are possibly not showing what is really happening. Can you please directly try `User.findOneAndUpdate({ "email": email, "addresses._id": address_id },{ "$set": { "addresses.$.primary_address": true},{ "new": true })` as was originally suggested. The returned document in the promise resolve should show the modification. Note `User` and do not `.findOne()` first, use model directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My money here would be on that the "address_id" value you are looking up does not actually match anything. Performing the `.update()` on a retrived document is generally not what you want anyway and this confuses the issue in the code.

Instead perform a [`.findOneAndUpdate()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOneAndUpdate) initially to both retrieve by the matched "email" and the "addresses._id" values as is done in this full example:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var addressSchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  primary: { type: Boolean, default: false }
});
var userSchema = new Schema({
  email: String,
  addresses: [addressSchema]
});
var User = mongoose.model('User',userSchema);

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/utest');
mongoose.set("debug",true);

await User.remove();

let user = await User.create({
  email: "example@example.com",
  addresses: [
    { "name": "One" },
    { "name": "Two" }
  ]
});
console.log("1️⃣", user);

user = User.findOneAndUpdate(
  {
    "email": user.email,
    "addresses._id": user.addresses[1]._id
  },
  {
    "$set": { "addresses.$.primary": true }
  },
  { "new": true }
)
console.log("2️⃣", user);

mongoose.disconnect();
```

This will consistently produce output like this:

```
1️⃣ { __v: 0,
  email: 'example@example.com',
  _id: 55ecf31a53558e183d208aa2,
  addresses:
   [ { name: 'One', _id: 55ecf31a53558e183d208aa4, primary: false },
     { name: 'Two', _id: 55ecf31a53558e183d208aa3, primary: false } ] }
2️⃣ { _id: 55ecf31a53558e183d208aa2,
  email: 'example@example.com',
  __v: 0,
  addresses:
   [ { name: 'One', _id: 55ecf31a53558e183d208aa4, primary: false },
     { name: 'Two', _id: 55ecf31a53558e183d208aa3, primary: true } ] }
```

And has debug ouput like this:

```
Mongoose: users.remove({}) {}
Mongoose: users.insert({ email: 'example@example.com', _id: ObjectId("55ecf35627cddb243d3d8e22"), addresses: [ { name: 'One', _id: ObjectId("55ecf35627cddb243d3d8e24"), primary: false }, { name: 'Two', _id: ObjectId("55ecf35627cddb243d3d8e23"), primary: false } ], __v: 0 })
Mongoose: users.findAndModify({ 'addresses._id': ObjectId("55ecf35627cddb243d3d8e23"), email: 'example@example.com' }) [] { '$set': { 'addresses.$.primary': true } } { new: true, upsert: false, remove: false }
```

This is just setting up the example, but the main thing happens with `.findOneAndUpdate()` where in the resolution of the promise you see the returned document as "updated" from the original form at the specified array element.

This is what you basically should be doing here, and any further modification to the returned document come "after" that initial "update and fetch" has been done.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you really have to use Mongoose, can't tell if that is a requirement from your question.

Here is the example with straight Monogodb driver:

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient
  , format = require('util').format;

MongoClient.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/test', function(err, db) {
if(err) throw err;

db.collection('test').findAndModify(
  {hello: 'world'}, // query
  [['_id','asc']],  // sort order
  {$set: {hi: 'there'}}, // replacement,     replaces only the field "hi"
  {}, // options
  function(err, object) {
      if (err){
          console.warn(err.message);  //     returns error if no matching object found
      }else{
          console.dir(object);
      }
  });
});
```